# Ruby: compare hash to hash value trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such part of "ghost look like" code (but it so must be, as db is huge and have many tables):

```
def search_group
    @search_trees = SearchTree.all
    @designation = Designation.find(:all, :conditions => { :DES_ID => @search_trees.map(&:STR_DES_ID)})
    @text = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => @designation.map(&:DES_TEX_ID)})
    @search_result = @text.find_all{|item| item.TEX_TEXT.include?(params[:search_group_text])}
    @designation_back = @designation.find_all{|item| item.DES_TEX_ID == @search_result.TEX_ID}
    @search_trees_back = @search_trees.find_all{|item| item.STR_DES_ID == @designation_back.DES_ID}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I try to compare

```
 @designation_back = @designation.find_all{|item| item.DES_TEX_ID == @search_result.TEX_ID}
```

but i get errors, something bad...undefined method `TEX_ID'. As i think, it's via i compare hash and hash in bad way... How can i do this?

Comment: try lowercase letters for method names. e.g. item.des_tex_id

Comment: @IuriG. as db is huge and have many tables, also it's non standart db! fields are ok

Comment: have you tried a lowercase method on just `@search_result.tex_id`?

Comment: @iconoclast if logger i see that object contain uppercase id!

Answer (score 0):

```
  @search_result = @text.find_all{|item| item.TEX_TEXT.include?(params[:search_group_text])}
  @designation_back = @designation.find_all{|item| item.DES_TEX_ID == @search_result.TEX_ID}
```

it's because `@search_result` is an array and not an object where you can call that method on.

Comment: it's an array! ARRAY?! got it? a list of objects. i can't tell you what to do with it, it's your business-logic!

Answer (score 0):

@search_results is an array. If you know it is returning just one result, you can do @search_results[0].Tex_Id, otherwise have to loop through for each value of @search_results.

try 'pry' gem to debug what results you are getting from each assignment.